# jQuery: how to get position of mouse relative to the top/left corner of an element taking into account scrollbars

Tags: jquery, mouseevent

I'm doing some work with the canvas element and need to track the mouse around highlighting parts of it.

I would like to be able get the position relative to the elements top left, 0 , 0.
I have this - using jQuery:

```
...
var pos = $(this).position();
var left = e.clientX - position.left;
var top = e.clientY - position.top;    
...
```

First is there an jQuery api that will do the above for me and secondly it fails miserably when the window has been scrolled up/down as the canvas is a lot bigger than the actual browser window so is there an api that takes that into account also.

TIA.

Comment: tried offset - didn't seem to work and I need to use the top/left of the element as the origin. offset seems to be giving me a left of zero when scrolled left and a strange top - -1 -2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should, depending on the browser, use `offsetX`/`offsetY` or `layerX`/`layerY` attributes of the [Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) to track the mouse relative to the element which you've bound the `mousemove` event to.

I made this small plugin which normalizes the above values and adds `mouseX` and `mouseY` to the Event Object.

```
(function($){
    var org = $.event,
        _super = {
            fix:  org.fix
        };
    $.extend($.event, {
        fix: function(event) {
            var self = _super.fix.apply(this, [event]);
            // Normalize offsetY/X and layerX/Y
            self.mouseX = (self.offsetX || self.layerX);
            self.mouseY = (self.offsetY || self.layerY);
            return self;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

See [test case on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/NkZDV/)

Comment: doesn't appear to work in my browser - firefox 6 - i just get the message "Left: undefined Top: undefined". And according to the link you gave there are no properties called that.

Comment: @push22 Ah... Seems Firefox uses `layerX` and `layerY` for this. Updated the test case!

Comment: that works for X/left but is always wrong for top - investigation needed. thanks.

Comment: @push22 It's not wrong here. Can you point me to a test case that reproduces this?

Comment: no its definitely a problem in my code, not sure where yet, but I get a top/left of 8/8 when I hover over the very top/left of the control. I will try and track it down tomorrow thanks.

Comment: @push22 Ah ok. I've updated my answer with a simple plugin that normalizes these values.

Answer (score 0):

managed to kinda fix it, after a fashion:

```
   var left = 0;
   var top = 0;
   if(e.offsetX) {
    left = e.offsetX;
    top = e.offsetY;
   } else {
    var offset = $(element).offset();
    left = e.layerX - offset.left;
    top = e.layerY - offset.top;
   }
```

moz needs the offset taken into account. Although i'm sure there must be a "proper" jquery api that hides this detail from me.

Also There's something "funny" going on with jsfiddle that the above example works ok - it didn't in a browser.

Of course I may just be speaking nonsense.